Issues with centering a modal overlay on mobile screens
I am working on a website with the structure as shown in this codepen. Modal-test . In codepen, there doesn't seem to be any issue when i open the Chrome devtools and toggle device toolbar to see how the website will function on mobile screens but if i open it as a local html page (with CSS and JS linked), the modal is not centered on the screen in that mode. Same issue with Firefox (however I noticed that as long I turn the touch simulation off in firefox, the modal is centered, turning it on un-centers it.)
function showModal() {
    if (modalVisible) return;

    modalVisible = true;
    modal.style.display = "flex";
    document.body.appendChild(modal);
  }

I have tried to figure out how to center the modal on the screen while also not scrolling away from the content underneath it but I just can't find the problem.

Problem in <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
I recommend use this code - <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" />
More information about viewport

When I open your code a local html, I see modal in center. screenshot 1
Maybe you forgot disable cache in browser? And you see previos versions of your code?
How to disable cache in Chrome screenshot 2

In responsive mode, the modal is centering for me too. Select one of the mobile devices and check if the modal is still centered for you.

iPhone SE - centering for me - https://snipboard.io/RuMVI3.jpg
Show me your Chrome settings?

Not centering for me. https://imgur.com/a/QWYYOMD Which Chrome settings do you need to see? Also, to test it on actual devices, i have it temporarily deployed at https://test-modal.pages.dev/ . Can you check with your mobile if it centers for you?

I see, we have different 
Replace  to , it's must help

It seems to be working now, thank you for your help. If you change your original answer or post a new one explaining the issue and solution, I will mark it as accepted.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
